# Opening Xcode on Mac

Tags: macos, xcode

I am new to Mac as well as Xcode. I have installed Xcode. When I click on Xcode on the toolbar or on Mac HD --> Applications --> Xcode, I do not see any editor opening. Please advise if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: It sometimes takes a minute or two for Xcode to open. Does the icon (blueprint with a hammer on it) appear in the Dock? Does it appear and then disappear, or not appear at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's address the new to Mac part and answer how to tell if an app is running.

From Finder - select the Go menu and select Utilities
Open Activity Monitor
Type Xcode in the search field.

[image]

You should now be able to tell if the program has launched or perhaps has quit itself already. To the left of the search box, you can find several filters to limit the processes that are shown.

Once you get Xcode launched, you can then use the Info or Sample tool to look at what it might be doing instead of drawing a window for you to start your development.

Also, if Xcode happens to start and have no windows, you may need to use the application switcher (command + tab) to bring it up and open the Xcode preferences and reset the "Don't show me" warnings from the general tab to see the welcome splash screen again.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some things to try
+ Try double clicking
+ Also you might be right-clicking on the mouse - try left-clicking.
+ If no luck, go to `Mac HD -> Applications`, then click once on the `Xcode` icon and choose <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> or Choose `Open` from the `File` menu (top left of screen).
+ Failing this - go to `Mac HD -> Applications -> Utilities` and open `Terminal`. Then run

```
open /Applications/XCode.app
```

If all these fail - post back the response from `Terminal`.

Also - please post your OS version, and the version of Xcode (click on `XCode` once and then type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> or choose `Get Info` from the `File` menu). The version number will be listed in the `General` section of the pop-up window.

Do you know how XCode was installed (e.g via AppStore or was it installed a download file)?

Answer (score 1):

When you open Xcode, you won't see any editor, that's true. You will be greeted with a splash screen. You have to choose "Create a new XCode project" or "Open Other", then only the editor comes to life.

[image: XCode Splash Screen]

Comment: This is the typical first launch, but I've also seen it freeze when you have iOS devices connected and for some reason it wants to bring up the Organizer and then realized it hasn't really run yet and barfs all over itself and never really runs. Usually the second launch works better.